# How do I individually set a form validation error message in CodeIgniter?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I would like to be able to set form validation error messages individually for my form.  Particularly for the "is unique" rule.  I writing a member registration form script that and I use that rule to validate the email address as well as the username.

`$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');`

The above code won't work for what I am trying to do.  If I set the message for the rule "is unique" it will display the same thing for both fields, assuming there are errors for both.  For example, if both the username and the email address are already in use(maybe the user forgot they already registered?), then it will be the same.  So I would like the "is unique" rule for the email address to say "The email address is already in use." or the username field would say "The username is already in use.".

Or if I can somehow insert the name of the field into the error message?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

```
<?php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('reg_email', Email, 'trim|xss_clean|required|valid_email|callback_check_email_exists');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', Username, 'trim|xss_clean|required|valid_email|callback_check_username_exists');


function check_email_exists($reg_email)
{
    $data['result'] = $this->general_model->check_record_exist('usermaster','Id',array('Email'=>$reg_email,'Status !='=>'Delete')); //check if same or not
    if (!empty($data['result']))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_email_exists', 'Email already exist');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
?>
```

Make same callback fun for username also and change the message. Try it tell me if u don't get anything.